# ARGV in perl not working

Tags: perl, argv

Below is the snippet that works,

```
open(C, "Inputfile.txt")  || die "Cannot open the file\n";
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use Math::Round
while(<C>)
```

I wish to pass the file name in command line. I tried to use ARGV but it is not working. I modified it to:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my $filename = $ARGV[1];
while($filename)
```

When I execute it with

```
perl file.pl inputfile.txt
```

I do not get any output. Can anyone say, why it is not working ?

Thanks,

AP

Comment: Try `$ARGV[0]`, maybe?  What is `$#ARGV`?

Comment: Always `use warnings` and `use strict`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issues

1. In your test case `$ARGV[1]` is not defined since Perl arrays are zero-indexed
2. You need to `open` a filehandle to `$filename`
3. You need to do `readline` on the filehandle, e.g. `while ( <$fh> ) { ... }`

That said, just use the diamond operator `<>` or `<ARGV>`:

```
while (<>) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$ARGV[0]`, not `[1]`.  Per [Perl Maven](https://perlmaven.com/argv-in-perl), `@ARGV` does not include the program name — that's separate variable `$0`.